# (Unity) Display Joined Room Name? Photon PUN

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I made a multiplayer game with photon unity, when a player has joined a room I want to display the name of the joined room in the scene
please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [`OnJoinedRoom`](https://documentation.help/Photon-Unity-Networking-1.91/class_photon_1_1_pun_behaviour.html#a8ee05dd443b9e51ddf962e655ca8ab77) and get the [`PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_network.html#a71754de2cf0bd33cddd33198aa3d6696) and then its [`Name`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_room.html#a7f5635847aeebcf1ab943bdfcae28498) like e.g.

```c#
public void OnJoinedRoom ()
{
    var roomName = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.Name;
    Debug.Log($"Joined room {roomName}");

    // ... However you want to display it e.g. assign it to an UI.Text or TextMeshPro etc
}
```